# How to check if all elements in a list have length of 5?

Tags: python

Say I have a lst = ["John", "Jack", "Elizabeth", "Smith"]

I want to check to see if all these names have less than 5 characters using all method. Both of what I tried below did not work.

```
if len(all(lst)) < 5:
    return "Everyone's names have less than five characters"
```

```
if all(len(lst)) < 5:
    return "Everyone's names have less than five characters"
```

I do wish to use the all method. Please help!

Comment: you could do something like `all(len(x) < 5 for x in your_list)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = ["John", "Jack", "Elizabeth", "Smith"]


if all(len(name) < 5 for name in lst):
    print('all names have length of 5 characters')
else:
    print('not all of names have length of 5 characters')
```